# Queue with multiple consumers and one producer

Tags: c#, queue, producer-consumer

I've written a queue supporting one producer and multiple consumer threads. The idea is that the queue instances a definable number of long running consumer threads. Internally I'm using a `BlockingCollection` to solve the producer consumer problem. I've done some little testing via a console application, and it seems to work. Can somebody review the code and let me know if there is any flaw?

The code can be found under [Github](https://github.com/moerwald/myCSharpToolbox/tree/master/source/Multithreading/ProducerConsumer).

Example usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var q = new QueueWithMultipleConsumerThreads<int>(
            numberOfWorkerThreads: 10,
            actionToBeCalled: i =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Consumed {i} from thread {Thread.CurrentThread.Name}, id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            });

    // Add some entries to the q
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        q.Enque(i);
    }

    Thread.Sleep(5000); // Give the q time to work
    q.Shutdown();
}
```

[QueueWithMultipleConsumerThreads:](https://github.com/moerwald/myCSharpToolbox/blob/master/source/Multithreading/ProducerConsumer/QueueWithMultipleConsumerThreads.cs)

```
public class  QueueWithMultipleConsumerThreads<T>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentBag<Thread> threads = new ConcurrentBag<Thread>();
    private readonly ConcurrentBag<Worker<T>> workers = new ConcurrentBag<Worker<T>>();
    private readonly BlockingCollection<T> queue = new BlockingCollection<T>();

    public QueueWithMultipleConsumerThreads(uint numberOfWorkerThreads, Action<T> actionToBeCalled  )
    {
        if (numberOfWorkerThreads == 0) { throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(numberOfWorkerThreads)} must be > 0"); }
        if (actionToBeCalled == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(actionToBeCalled));}

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfWorkerThreads; i++)
        {
            // Create a worker and assign it to a thread
            var threadName = $"Worker thread {i}";
            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(threadName);

            var w = new Worker<T>(this.queue, threadName, actionToBeCalled, logger);
            var t = new Thread(w.DoWork) { IsBackground = true, Name = threadName};

            this.workers.Add(w);
            this.threads.Add(t);
            t.Start();
        }
    }

    public void Enque(T item)
    {
        this.queue.Add(item);
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return this.queue.Count;
    }

    public void Shutdown()
    {
        while (!this.workers.IsEmpty)
        {
            Worker<T> w;
            this.workers.TryTake(out w);
            w?.RequestStop();
        }

        while (!this.threads.IsEmpty)
        {
            Thread t;
            this.threads.TryTake(out t);
            t?.Join(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

[Worker:](https://github.com/moerwald/myCSharpToolbox/blob/master/source/Multithreading/ProducerConsumer/Worker.cs)

```
/// <summary>
/// A worker receives a collection to take elements from. After an element was successfully retrieved it will call <see cref="actionToBeCalled"/>. 
/// Stopping the worker can be done via <see cref="RequestStop"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class Worker<T>
{
    public Worker(BlockingCollection<T> collection, string workerName, Action<T> actionToBeCalled, ILog logger)
    {
        if (collection == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collection));}
        if (workerName == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workerName));}
        if (actionToBeCalled == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(actionToBeCalled));}
        if (logger == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));}

        this.collection = collection;
        this.workerName = workerName;
        this.actionToBeCalled = actionToBeCalled;
        this.cancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        this.cancelationToken = this.cancelationTokenSource.Token;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        while (!this.shouldStop)
        {
            try
            {
                var item = this.collection.Take(this.cancelationToken); // Take should block, until an element was added.
                this.actionToBeCalled?.Invoke(item);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.logger.Warn($"[{this.workerName}]: Exception occurred: {exception}");
            }
        }

        this.logger.Debug($"[{this.workerName}]: Shutdown gracefully");
    }

    public void RequestStop()
    {
        this.logger.Debug($"[{this.workerName}]: {nameof(this.RequestStop)}");
        this.cancelationTokenSource.Cancel();
        this.shouldStop = true;
    }
    // Volatile is used as hint to the compiler that this data member will be accessed by multiple threads.
    private volatile bool shouldStop;

    private readonly BlockingCollection<T> collection;

    private readonly string workerName;

    private readonly Action<T> actionToBeCalled;

    private readonly CancellationToken cancelationToken;

    private readonly CancellationTokenSource cancelationTokenSource;

    private readonly ILog logger;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't really create a `CancellationTokenSource` inside your workers. Instead you should create single instance inside your queue and pass the same token to all workers. Then you can use `cancelationTokenSource.Cancel()` inside `Shutdown` method to send a cancellation signal to every worker. Also, instead of using `shouldStop`, you should use `token.IsCancellationRequested` flag.

It is the other way around with worker threads. Those should probably be created by workers themselves, so you do not have to store them separately. Good job on actually `Join`ing the threads you create, that's a good thing to do. But the timeout smells. Are you sure that you are not hiding an error? If threads successfully join every time, then you should call regular `Join()` without timeout, if they do not - that is something you should investigate and fix.

Finally, you should pay attention to classes that implement `IDisposable`. Nothing horrible will probably happen if you forget to dispose them, but still it is a good idea to clean things up yourself when you are done using your `CancellationTokenSource`s or your `BlockingCollection`s.

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback. I`ve adapted the code to your suggestions -> Code becomes more clear, code size reduced :-). I`ve commited the changes to the Github repository.